# Merge two dataframes , one having weekly dates and the other having monthly dates, with the output showing weekly dates and other columns from second

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have two dataframes :- a and b, where a has a monthly frequency in the date column and b has a weekly frequency in the date column.
Input dataframe representation :-
dataframe 'a'

[image]

dataframe 'b'

[image]

I want to replace the date column(monthly) in dataframe'a' with the date column(weekly) from dataframe'b' and fill the 'barley_yie' column based on the country and date(monthly) values.

The end dataframe should be like this:-

| date | country | barley_yie |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | Argentina | 3.33 |
| 2020-01-07 | Argentina | 3.33 |
| 2020-01-14 | Argentina | 3.33 |

Answer (score 1):

First pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), add another DataFrame by [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) and last melting to original format by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df1 = a.pivot(index='date', columns='country', values='barley_yie')
#if duplicates
#df1 = a.pivot_table(index='date', columns='country', values='barley_yie', aggfunc='mean')
df = (pd.merge_asof(df1, b[['date']], left_index=True, right_on='date')
        .melt('date', var_name='country', value_name='barley_yie')
        .dropna(subset=['barley_yie']))
```

Comment: Got the output using below snippet :
```
 df_test_1 = (a.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W-Fri', key='date'),'country'])['barley_yield_mtha']
      .mean()
      .reset_index())

df_test_2 = df_test_1.merge(b[['date']].drop_duplicates())
s = pd.to_datetime(df_test_2['date'])
u = (df_test_2.assign(Weeks=[pd.date_range(*x,freq='W')
                  for x in zip(s,s.add(pd.offsets.MonthEnd()))]).explode("Weeks"))
u.drop(['date', 'Weeks'], axis=1, inplace=True)
u["Date"] = u["Weeks_orig"]
u.drop(['Weeks_orig'], axis=1, inplace=True)
u = u[['Date', 'country', 'barley_yield_mtha']]
```